# Merge 2 columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe :

```
   id   p    means    temp
0   1  p1  means11  t11
1   1  p1  means12  t12
2   1  p1  means13  t13
3   2  p2  means21  t21
4   2  p2  means22  t22
5   2  p2  means23  t23
```

I want to merge means and t and create another columns such do that is the element is a mean 'True' if the element is t 'False'

```
   id   p    means      eval
0   1  p1  means11  true
1   1  p1  means12  true
2   1  p1  means13  true
3   1  p1  t11     false
4   1  p1  t12     false
5   1  p1  t13     false
6   2  p2  means21 true
7   2  p2  means22 true
7   2  p2  means23 true
8   2  p2  t21     false 
9   2  p2  t22     false 
10   2  p2  t23     false
```

Merge 2 columns in a dataframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: Please elaborate on your output, is it complete? If not, please fix it, if yes then explain the logic.

Comment: I fixed it, hope this clarify it a bit

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your output is incomplete, it looks like a `melt` after `rename`:

```
df.rename(columns={'meas': 'f'}).melt(['id', 'p'], var_name='eval', value_name='meas')
```

Output:

```
    id   p eval    meas
0    1  p1    f  meas11
1    1  p1    f  meas12
2    1  p1    f  meas13
3    2  p2    f  meas21
4    2  p2    f  meas22
5    2  p2    f  meas23
6    1  p1    t     t11
7    1  p1    t     t12
8    1  p1    t     t13
9    2  p2    t     t21
10   2  p2    t     t22
11   2  p2    t     t23
```

Comment: sorry the example was off, I don't think renaming solve the issue

Comment: @zahraelhamraoui apart for the order of the rows in the output, I don't see how yours differ. Is the order important?

Comment: yes the order is indeed important